# Custom control(custom table) and drag it on to radeditor

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I want to design a custom control which is having html text and drag it on to radeditor(eg: drag and drop a custom table created with default css)

May i know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am still not getting what you want, but from your question may be you want something to design the controls. But it is paid version

[Telerik link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Basically i want to extend the radeditor by adding a custom dialog control in the tools section and be able to drag and drop at a poition on the radeditor

Comment: @Ramesh: I think they have their support forum you can post it their, that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Start by examining this to see how you can listen to the drop event in the editor content area and use its **pasteHtml**() method to add the content you want: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/treeviewandeditor/defaultcs.aspx

Without a control to provide you the drop event, you need to attach it yourself: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-attacheventhandler.html. Here is a sample:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function OnClientLoad(editor, args) {
                editor.attachEventHandler("drop", function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                                            editor.pasteHtml(e.srcElement.toString());
                });
            }
        </script>
        <telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad">
        </telerik:RadEditor>
```

So, with this, you can generate the content you like.
NOTE: some browser will handle drag and drop by themselves and add elements to the content.

Another option is to create a custom comamnd that will directly insert your desired HTML if it is static: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-adding-your-own-buttons.html.